# When object is allocated outside of TLAB?

Tags: java

I read quite a few posts about TLAB in java, they all mentioned that if TLAB is enabled, for small objects jvm will tried TLAB first before allocating in heap, but what about an object that one thread created may be shared by multiple threads? can it be allocated in TLAB? from what ways jvm can use to decide to or not to use TLAB, besides large objects?